# Nhibernate : Updating a child entity directly without inverse

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using fluent nhibernate to map a parent child relationship to the sql database.
Most of the times i let the parent entity save it's child entities,they are inserted in 1 transaction and if i'm not mistaken this wouldn't be possible if i used .Inverse() and sql identity columns.
The problem i have is that in 1 specific case i want to update the child entity and ONLY the child entity.
When i do this with my current setup the child record will lose the relationship to it's parent(if the parent object is null) or will replace my parent object completely(if i insert a dummy parent with just an id).

Does anyone know a way to achieve a single record update without affecting the foreign key?

 I can think of a manual sql statement or a stored procedure but i'm hoping there is an nhibernate way.

I have the following setup (simplified for your convenience) :

```
public ProjectMap()
{
  Table("Project");
  Id(p=> p.Id);
  HasMany(p => p.Risks).Not.LazyLoad();
}

public RiskMap()
{
  Table("ProjectRisk");
  Id(r=> r.Id);
  References(r => r.Project).Column("ProjectId");
  Map(r => r.Description);
}

public class Project
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Risk> Risks { get; set; }
}

public class Risk
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Description{ get; set; }
  public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What were you trying to do? Can you post the code in question? When updating existing Risk, loaded from db, Project property should remain intact if you don't set it manually.

Comment: Because i'm using a soap service in between(it was a hard requirement) i'm not serializing the Project property. If i did then all the child items would have it's parent item and i'd have a endless loop of serialing them(not to mention the data transmitted). And even if the reference object was there it would still get updated if any other changes have been made.

Comment: To clarify exactly what i'm doing : mvc websites loads a project through the soap service. On client click it sends 1 risk object back to the webserver to be saved in the database.

Comment: Then maybe you should load the Risk from db, using its Id, update its properties using the sent instance and save it. Or if performance is critical, do HQL update: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct

Comment: I can see both of your solutions working but it gives me the feeling that i'm fighting against nhibernate(either by manually filling/updating an object or manually making the query) and not letting nhibernate do the work for me. Best case scenario would be a line of code to invert the control for this single instance or to add a property to the object to not trigger other saves or something. So far my googling hasn't produced anything which seems to fit so i might indeed be forced to use 1 of your solutions.

Comment: Well, to tell you the truth, I wouldn't allow my domain objects to cross the layer boundary in the first place. Sending DTOs over the SOAP would be more appropriate.

Comment: Forgive me for not mentioning as i thought it didn't matter but i am using dto's and converting them back en forth to my domain objects. How would this change my problem? The project object isn't lost due to serialization but due to conversion to a dto. When converting it back it is still lost.

Comment: What I have been doing usually, is when mapping a DTO (view model in my case), I'm first loading the entity by ID from the repository, and then mapping all other properties from DTO to domain entity - using AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Miroslav suggested i'm using an HQL update statement now.

It's a little messy for my taste but it gets the job done.

```
Session.CreateQuery("update Risk set Closed = :completed where Id = :id")
                    .SetInt32("id", id)
                    .SetBoolean("completed", completed)
                    .ExecuteUpdate();
```